# What is the probability that a randomly selected integer is even?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, soft-question

Preface:

The point of this question is to find an effective means of defining the probability of a particular infinite set of events within another infinite set of events, using $2\Bbb{Z}\subset\Bbb{Z}$ as a simple (I hope) example. This is the first step towards answering more essential questions like "what is the likelihood that the solution to a differential equation can be obtained analytically?", which in turn form the basis for effective decision making (e.g. should I attempt an analytical solution?).

I would like to define the probability in such a way that the ordering of the set does not affect it (if this is at all possible). This is likely to require a different notion of 'size' from cardinality. In particular, while the cardinality of $\Bbb{Z}$ and $2\Bbb{Z}$ are the same, there is some sense in which the integers are 'larger' than the even numbers by virtue of being a superset.

The 'size' of a set, considered in this manner, must account for the number of *distinct* things in the set - i.e. replacement fails.

In the general case, the answer to the question "what is the probability that an element of $B$ is in $A$ given $A\subset B$ is trivially $0$ whenever $A$ is finite, and $1$ whenever $B\setminus A$ is finite, independent of the ordering of $A$ and $B$, because the probability of a finite number of events within an infinite number of events is infinitesimally small.

This approach fails when $B\setminus A$ and $A$ are both infinite.

---

That being said, I would argue that there is at least *some* probability $0<p<1$ such that $n\in\Bbb{Z}.P(n\in2\Bbb{Z})=p$. The reasoning is quite simple:

Q: Suppose that $n$ is a natural number. What is the probability that $n$ is an integer?

A: $1$, because the natural numbers are a subset of the integers.

Generalization: if $A\subseteq B$, then the probability that a randomly selected element of $A$ is an element of $B$ is $1$ - if not, then it must be possible to select an element of $A$ which is not in $B$ (contradiction)$^1$

Q: Suppose that $n$ is a natural number. What is the probability that $n$ is imaginary?

A: $0$, because no natural number is imaginary.

Generalization: if $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then the probability that a randomly selected element of $A$ is an element of $B$ is $0$ - if not, then the intersection of $A$ and $B$ must contain at least one element (contradiction)$^2$

From this, it seems reasonable to say that if $A$ is a nonempty subset of $B$ (such that $|A|=|B|$), then the probability that a randomly selected element of $B$ is in $A$ is greater than $0$ (because the intersection is nonempty) and less than $1$ (because the complement of $A$ is nonempty). In other words, if $A\subset B$, then the probability that $a\in A$ given $a\in B$ lies in the interval $(0,1)$.$^3$ As $2\Bbb{Z}\subset\Bbb{Z}$, the probability of a randomly selected integer being even should fall somewhere in the interval $(0,1)$.

Intuitively, I want to say that $p=0.5$, and I can provide a loose justification as to why this should be. However, I am hoping to find a more formal (and preferably consistent) means of addressing this and similar problems.

---

$^1$ The brief application of some nonstandard techniques potentially suggests that if the set $A\setminus B$ is *nonempty* but *finite*, then the [standard part of the] probability of a randomly selected element of $A$ being in $B$ is $1$. Conversely, the [st.p. of] probability that a randomly selected element of $A$ is in $B$ is *less* than $1$ iff $A\setminus B$ is not finite.

Caveat: The cardinalities of $A$ and $B$ must be interpreted as hyperintegers (the same cardinal may correspond to more than one hyperinteger) - hence $A$ and $B$ must be countable. This may or may not lead to a problem with the continuum hypothesis, but I haven't looked into it. For now, this is just a rough guess based on the properties of infinity discussed by Keisler & co.

$^2$ Again, a nonstandard interpretation would suggest that if $A\cap B$ is finite, then the probability of a randomly selected element of $A$ being an element of $B$ is effectively $0$. Conversely, the probability that a randomly selected element of $A$ is in $B$ is *greater* than $0$ iff $A\cap B$ is not finite.

$^3$ This only makes sense when neither $A$ nor $B\setminus A$ is finite.

Comment: I don't understand the analogy with complex numbers.  As to the given question, the simplest approach is to let $p_N$ be the usual probability when you limit the integers to those of absolute value less than $N$.  Then try to take the limit as $N\to \infty$.  That works perfectly well here, and you get $\frac 12$.  No need for any abstract apparatus.

Comment: @lulu That would suggest that an alteration to the ordering of the integers would alter the probability that a randomly selection integer is even. Ex $\Bbb{Z}=1,-1,3,-3,5,-5,7\ldots,2,-2,4,-4,6,\ldots\implies P(n\in 2\Bbb{Z})=0$

Comment: See [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density)

Comment: @lulu I had hoped to define the probability so that the ordering of the set cannot make it seem like "an integer is never even".

Comment: Yes, of course.  If you don't specify an ordering, I have no idea how you'd distinguish one infinite set of integers from another.  Set theoretically, all infinite countable sets are the same.

Comment: @R.Burton : If the dots in the middle stand for an infinity of elements, then that construction is not an ordering. Of course you can define an order on $\Bbb Z$ with that pattern, but you can not enumerate $\Bbb Z$ that way.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "randomly selected", what is the exact definition/characterization of that process? Can you give an algorithm for it, for instance using a source of random bits, where the output is that integer?

Comment: @LutzL The order type as written is $\omega\cdot 2$. It is an ordering, but not the usual one. You can construct an order isomorphism with the ordering $1,2,3,\ldots,0,-1,-2,\ldots$. From a purely set-theoretical perspective this is the 'same' ordering.

Comment: @LutzL I was considering a naive concept of randomness ('true randomness', in the classical sense) when I asked the question. Such an algorithm (should it exist) will invariably loop indefinitely. I don't know enough about the formal definitions of randomness to say any more than that.

Comment: You are working with infinite sets. There is rarely the case that "naive" ideas about infinity work out in the way they were intended. Also, there is nothing classical about probabilities on infinite sets. The theory of probability spaces, sigma algebras of events and probability measures was invented to go from finite event atom spaces to infinite ones.

Comment: In your case $A$ is the set of odd numbers, $B$ is the set of numbers. There are two sets, so what is the issue?

Comment: What I was asking about was basically an un-compression algorithm. Given an infinite sequence of zeros and ones, produce a number. Of course, one would have to care about the output format (What with numbers with more than $10^{100}$ digits). And then one could translate probabilities on the sequence space to probabilities on the integers. But that does not really help here, you have to start with a probability density on the integers, and then the answer is easy, just sum the probabilities up.

Comment: @copper.hat : It seems OP wants to somehow implement the idea of an uniform distribution to the integers, without running into the obvious obstacle. Thus the flight into NSA ideas.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments point out, the usual way is to define a finite density and then take a limit. For example the probability of $k$ being even can be defined via:

$$p_n(k)=\frac{|\{2\mathbb{Z}\cap [n]\}|}{|\{\mathbb{Z}\cap [n]\}|}$$

with $p(k)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_n(k)=1/2$.

It’s important to understand that the resulting limit is NOT a probability because there is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb{Z}$. It’s just a density, which correlates with our intuition of probability.

Unfortunately it’s not possible to make this density permutation invariant. For example, construct a bijection that looks something like $1,2,3,5,4,7,9,11,13,6,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,8,...$, eg where the even numbers get exponentially spaced apart. In this case the density will be 0 in the limit.

Comment: Would it be possible to take an 'average' of the density over the set of all possible permutations? Perhaps using calculus (seeing as how the set of such permutations is uncountable)?

Comment: @R.Burton: Neat question. If I'm not mistaken, that would always give 1/2. Every permutation that gives you density $x$ in the limit, has a complementary permutation that gives you $1-x$. I'm a bit hazy on whether that's a bijection though.